# what is the SQL prepared stament for lo_import in postgreSQL

Tags: c++, sql, database, postgresql, odbc

In postgreSQL we have option to import the file into database using lo_import method, which returns a OID using that we can export the file from database to the filesystem.
eg:
describe test table

**name text, file_id oid**

```
insert into test values('arul_test',lo_import('/home/arul/test.txt'));
```

prepared statement would be

```
insert into test values(?,?);
```

prepared statement for name will be SQLCHAR

What is the prepared statement for the file_id (note: here need to consider lo_import id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query to prepare should be

```
insert into test values(?,lo_import(?));
```

You proposal `insert into test values(?,?)` can't work because you can't submit a SQL function call (`lo_import`) as the value for a placeholder (`?`). Placeholders only fit where a literal value would fit.

When you're asking what's the prepared statement for `field_id` presumably you mean what's the ODBC type, but as it turns out what needs to be passed is a filename, so the type would be `SQLCHAR`.

Comment: Hi Deni  I have accepted.i have one more doubt in large object delete in   case   : postgres if i run command select lo_unlink(oID); for 1 million imported files of total 4GB in size. then it is removing in postgres. but the used space is not decreasing. how can i really remove that files from the postgres to reduce the usage space .

Comment: @ArulTheBoss: the space freed will be reused if importing other objects. Otherwise only `VACUUM FULL pg_largeobject;` will truly free the disk space. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/vacuum-returning-disk-space-to-operating-system

Comment: command "VACUUM FULL pg_largeobject;" desctoy in which basis?. Will it remove all the oid's or only  delete executed oid [ select lo_unlink(oid)]

Comment: VACUUM is a garbage collector. See the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html

Comment: @Deni: Thank you for your clarification. I have one more postgres performance related doubt. if i want to do a repeatively insert many entries then prepare stament and bind stament is same but bind variables only differ . Can i able to change the bind variables alone while executing all the staments.  `code` eg: stament insert into test(?,?); // prepare only once
bind_variable(var1, var2); // bind only once
int i=0, j=0;
while(1000 times) {var1 = i, var2 = j; // change the variables repeatedly 1000 times 
     sqlExecute(stamt);  // execute 1000 times 
     i ++; j++;
      }  `code`